# Creating makefiles in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, makefile

I have two python programs. say a.py and b.py. I build an index in a.py and then run b.py which import a.py.

I want to make a python makefile to install the two porgrams such as I go to my makefile and run :

./install - it installs the project in current directory
./a.py - interprets a.py
./b.py - interprets b.py

Any idea how to make this or pointers where I could find resource for this ?

Comment: Have you considered [distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/library/distutils.html)? It's a commonly used package that does what it sounds like you want to do.

Comment: have but found it a little confusing. Could provide with some detail to help get me started ?

Comment: Just make a.py build the index if it doesn't already exist. That way the first time it's imported it will take care of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get started with python `distutils`, you just need to create a `setup.py` file. See [the python reference](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) for the documentation of `setup.py`, and see [a real example here](https://github.com/emmett9001/candela/blob/master/setup.py).

Once you've made a `setup.py` file that is appropriate to your project structure, you can install the project by running `python setup.py install`. See [this](http://docs.python.org/2/install/#the-new-standard-distutils) for additional commands.

Comment: In addition to @Emmett's answer, you might want to check out [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging 1.0 documentation](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), especially the [Quick start tutorial](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)